# How to debug sql connection establishment c# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

im trying to create a login form

table userlogin has id,username,passwort

```
var user = rjTextBox1.Text;
        var pass = rjTextBox2.Text;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;database=exstructa;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select benutzername, passwort from userlogin where benutzername = @Username and passwort = @Password", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read() == true)
            {
                Dashboard dashboardform = new Dashboard();
                dashboardform.Show();
                this.Hide();
                MessageBox.Show("Willkommen", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falsche Zugangsdaten", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

trying to login with an identical existing user in the db still gives me an error, is there something wrong with the code or how can i debug the connection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I didnt get any, it skipped to else exc

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  They are different.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP MySQL as Service for testing purposes

Comment: Try to remove the `where clause` from the select statement and see what happens. If the code run as intended, then you may misspelled the uname or pwd, or even the record is not existed in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code with this:

```
try
{
   ...your code...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"{ex.Message}", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
catch(MySQLException sqlex)
{
   foreach(MySQLErrorCode err in sqlex.Errors)
   {
      //handle errors
      MessageBox.Show($"{err.Number}", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
}
```

And check what errors come out.

Comment: I changed it to MySQLException and MySQLErrorCode but still tells me no definition for .Numbers

Comment: Sory, it´s mySQL and not SQLServer...my bad. Try to connect using MySQL Workbench, or add another "catch" for Exception (cath(Exception ex)...has edited in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

It threw the Exception "Not Supported" and it seems that as of today, Visual Studio 2022 doesn't support MySQL yet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).